# How to show count of selected checkboxes in a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  let m = this.length, i;
  while (m) {
    i = (Math.random() * m--) >>> 0;
    [this[m], this[i]] = [this[i], this[m]]
  }
  return this;
}

$('#select_random').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    let minnum = 3, maxnum = 6
    let rand = Math.min(maxnum, Math.floor(Math.random() * ($('.check').length - 1 - minnum)) + minnum)
    //create our keys array
    let keyArray = [...Array($('.check').length).keys()].shuffle().slice(0, rand)
    keyArray.forEach((chk_i, i) => {
      if (i < rand) $($('.check').get(chk_i)).prop('checked', true)
    })
  } else {
    $('.check').prop('checked', false);
  }
});

const selectedElm = document.getElementById('selected');

function showChecked(){
  selectedElm.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=check]:checked').length;
}

document.querySelectorAll("input[name=check]").forEach(i=>{
 i.onclick = () => showChecked();
});
```

**Using this script to select random amount of checkboxes in table.
Want to show count number of selected checkboxes count.
Tried some sample not working. Tried this example, not working for me. Tring to get result in div span area like below.**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select Random <input type='checkbox' id="select_random"></label>
<div id="result">Total Number of Items Selected = <span id="selected">0</span></div>
 
<div class='cb'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"> checkbox <br />
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `Tried some sample not working. Tried this example, not working for me.` What exactly did you try? How is it not working? What was the result of what you tried?

Comment: Hi, sorry. Added missed count code I tried. Please check and help.

Comment: You have duplicate `class` attributes in your inputs, which isn't allowed and I don't think that `[]` is allowed in a class name, but you *can* include multiple classes by delimiting with a space, such as `class="class1 class2 check"`. Additionally, your `showChecked()` function uses a selector with `input[name=check]`, but none of your inputs have `name` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
let checked = $(".check:checked");
```

in your case :

```
$(".check:checked").length // will return count of checked checkboxes;
```

i hope it was useful

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snippet showing how to count checked checkboxes. If I have misunderstood your problem, let me/us know and I will either alter or delete this answer

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length);
```

```html
1<input type="checkbox" checked/>
2<input type="checkbox" checked/>
3<input type="checkbox"/>
4<input type="checkbox" checked/>
```

Comment: *`input:checked`* could be any input! Use rather the more specific class `.check:checked`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution

```
const checkboxContainer = document.querySelector('.cb');

function showChecked(){
  selectedElm.innerHTML = checkboxContainer.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
}
```

You want to limit the search to a parent container tag and also filter out by input type.